# Use External Javascript File Function in RegisterStartupScript Method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, registerstartupscript

I put together my whole javascript functions in one file(let's say it for making clear, javascriptsample.js).

And i need to use one of the function, which is in that file, in my asp.net side using RegisterStartupScript.

How can i call this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must give a reference of the `javascriptsample.js` in your aspx page...

Aftre that you can use..

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "tmp", "<script type='text/javascript'>JavascriptFunctionname();</script>", false);
```